How to swipe an item of a RecyclerView by pressing a Button
I want to know if it's possible to swipe to left an item of a RecyclerView by pressing a Button inside the same item. I tried using startSwipe() function of ItemTouchHelper but I couldn't make it work.

Could you please provide a video reference that will help me visualize this output?

@HanifShaikh Something like this: https://gyazo.com/b4bdb4abdc663ee94f26e10967fb0a7c                Swipe to left but when pressing a Button inside the item and when pressing it back, go back to previous position and swipe right

As I see inside your shared resource, there is no click on the item; it's swiping the item. I was confused; you want a swipe function but without swiping.

@MohammadHanifShaikh I want both, swipe I want swipe function and swipe by pressing button, in this example there is no click on the item because i couldn't make it work and I removed it.

Just implement ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback and then call the implementation of: onSwiped(ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction), where viewHolder is the current RecyclerView.ViewHolder and direction is one of: ItemTouchHelper.UP, ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT or ItemTouchHelper.LEFT.
